# Selenium: Unable to locate email type box, not within any iframe

Tags: selenium

I am trying to detect the login id and password field of a website : https://mretailstore.com/login but seems selenium is not able to locate the email type box. I have checked stackoverflow but didn't get any solution to this. Someone has used iframe because of what he/she was facing the same issue but here we have not incorporated any iframe. 
The error I am getting is:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .//*[@id='identity']

The code I am using:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\MI SERVICE\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
    FirefoxOptions capa = new FirefoxOptions();
    capa.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capa);

    driver.get("https://www.mretailstore.com/");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='identity']")).sendKeys("abc@d.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("abc123");

    driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();

    driver.navigate().back();

    driver.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks your xpath is correct only and this exception is happening before element rendering.So, Please add the some explicit wait after the page loading.

It is working for me with/without Explicit Wait.

**Code:**

```
driver.get("https://www.mretailstore.com/");

WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Login"));

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='identity']")).sendKeys("abc@d.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("abc123");

driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me after adding the wait time.

Comment: Glad to know,it helped:)